# MD Parola Animated Clock Help

Tags: arduino-nano, max7219

I wanted to create a clock with the animation as shown in this article given below, please watch the video almost at the end to view the animation (if the first link doesn't work for some reason try the second link) :-

https://www.hackster.io/mircemk/esp8266-animated-clock-on-8x8-led-matrices-4867ae#code

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mO98BBGWHkg

The thing is he doesn't uses the same library as me so its hard to replicate his code because he has done everything manually (printing chars first and then creating a function to print strings) while mine handles everything on its own.

The problem I am facing is that if I were to use a string to store the time received from the rtc it will scroll the string entirely which is not desired.
I have tired zoning the display but that will not work because I quickly realized that although its technically possible to replicate the animation using zones with the Parola library it will be inefficient because each MSB and LSB of every time component will require a zone.

Then I stumbled on this discussion on the Arduino Forum :-

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/positional-control-in-md-parola/1143151/20

The creator of this discussion is experiencing a similar problem and the creator of the library Marco_C instructed him to try to work with the GetGraphicObject() functionality to implement the pushWheel example of another library. I was successful in doing what the library creator asked from the discussion owner but was unsuccessful in displaying the time. This is what I was able to do , this example below is from the MD_MAX7219 library but made to work with the Parola library using the getGraphicObject() function and works flawlessly :-

```
#include <MD_Parola.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

#define MAX_DEVICES 8
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW

#define CLK_PIN 13
#define DATA_PIN 11
#define CS_PIN 10

MD_Parola matrix = MD_Parola(HARDWARE_TYPE, DATA_PIN, CLK_PIN, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
RTC_DS1307 rtc;

#define CHAR_SPACING 1            // pixels between characters
#define CHAR_COLS 8               // should match the fixed width character columns
#define ANIMATION_FRAME_DELAY 20  // in milliseconds

struct digitData {
  uint8_t oldValue, newValue;  // ASCII value for the character
  uint8_t index;               // animation progression index
  uint32_t timeLastFrame;      // time the last frame started animating
  uint8_t charCols;            // number of valid cols in the charMap
  uint8_t charMap[CHAR_COLS];  // character font bitmap
};

void updateDisplay(uint16_t numDigits, struct digitData *d)
// do the necessary to display current bitmap buffer to the LED display
{
  uint8_t   curCol = 0;

  matrix.getGraphicObject()->control(MD_MAX72XX::UPDATE, MD_MAX72XX::OFF);
  matrix.getGraphicObject()->clear();

  for (int8_t i = numDigits - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    for (int8_t j = d[i].charCols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
      matrix.getGraphicObject()->setColumn(curCol++, d[i].charMap[j]);
    }
    curCol += CHAR_SPACING;
  }

  matrix.getGraphicObject()->control(MD_MAX72XX::UPDATE, MD_MAX72XX::ON);
}

boolean displayValue(uint16_t value)
// Display the required value on the LED matrix and return true if an animation is current
// Finite state machine will ignore new values while animations are underway.
// Needs to be called repeatedly to ensure animations are completed smoothly.
{
  const uint8_t DIGITS_SIZE = 2;
  static struct digitData digit[DIGITS_SIZE];

  const uint8_t ST_INIT = 0, ST_WAIT = 1, ST_ANIM = 2;
  static uint8_t  state = ST_INIT;

  // finite state machine to control what we do
  switch(state)
  {
    case ST_INIT: // Initialize the display - done once only on first call
      for (int8_t i = DIGITS_SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        // separate digits
        digit[i].oldValue = '0' + value % 10;
        value = value / 10;
      }

      // Display the starting number
      for (int8_t i = DIGITS_SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        digit[i].charCols = matrix.getGraphicObject()->getChar(digit[i].oldValue, CHAR_COLS, digit[i].charMap);
      }
      updateDisplay(DIGITS_SIZE, digit);

      // Now we wait for a change
      state = ST_WAIT;
      break;

    case ST_WAIT: // not animating - save new value digits and check if we need to animate
      for (int8_t i = DIGITS_SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        // separate digits
        digit[i].newValue = '0' + value % 10;
        value = value / 10;

        if (digit[i].newValue != digit[i].oldValue)
        {
          // a change has been found - we will be animating something
          state = ST_ANIM;
          // initialize animation parameters for this digit
          digit[i].index = 0;
          digit[i].timeLastFrame = 0;
        }
      }

      if (state == ST_WAIT) // no changes - keep waiting
        break;
      // else fall through as we need to animate from now

    case ST_ANIM: // currently animating a change
      // work out the new intermediate bitmap for each character
      // 1. Get the 'new' character bitmap into temp buffer
      // 2. Shift this buffer down or up by current index amount
      // 3. Shift the current character by one pixel up or down
      // 4. Combine the new partial character and the existing character to produce a frame
      for (int8_t i = DIGITS_SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        if ((digit[i].newValue != digit[i].oldValue) && // values are different
           (millis() - digit[i].timeLastFrame >= ANIMATION_FRAME_DELAY)) // timer has expired
        {
          uint8_t newChar[CHAR_COLS] = { 0 };

          matrix.getGraphicObject()->getChar(digit[i].newValue, CHAR_COLS, newChar);
          if (((digit[i].newValue > digit[i].oldValue) ||    // incrementing
             (digit[i].oldValue == '9' && digit[i].newValue == '0')) && // wrapping around on increase
             !(digit[i].oldValue == '0' && digit[i].newValue == '9'))   // not wrapping around on decrease
          {
            // scroll down
            for (uint8_t j = 0; j < digit[i].charCols; j++)
            {
              newChar[j] = newChar[j] >> (COL_SIZE - 1 - digit[i].index);
              digit[i].charMap[j] = digit[i].charMap[j] << 1;
              digit[i].charMap[j] |= newChar[j];
            }
          }
          else
          {
            // scroll up
            for (uint8_t j = 0; j < digit[i].charCols; j++)
            {
              newChar[j] = newChar[j] << (COL_SIZE - 1 - digit[i].index);
              digit[i].charMap[j] = digit[i].charMap[j] >> 1;
              digit[i].charMap[j] |= newChar[j];
            }
          }

          // set new parameters for next animation and check if we are done
          digit[i].index++;
          digit[i].timeLastFrame = millis();
          if (digit[i].index >= COL_SIZE )
            digit[i].oldValue = digit[i].newValue;  // done animating
        }
      }

      updateDisplay(DIGITS_SIZE, digit);  // show new display

      // are we done animating?
      {
        boolean allDone = true;

        for (uint8_t i = 0; allDone && (i < DIGITS_SIZE); i++)
        {
          allDone = allDone && (digit[i].oldValue == digit[i].newValue);
        }

        if (allDone) state = ST_WAIT;
      }
      break;

    default:
      state = 0;
  }

  return(state == ST_WAIT);   // animation has ended
}

void setup() {
  rtc.begin();
  matrix.begin();
}

void loop() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  displayValue(now.second());
}
```

Now I need some help in implementing the same animation which this above code uses to display seconds to display time in this format "Hours:Minutes:Seconds" with each of the component MSB and LSB being animated individually. I have tried to make the example non blocking so that I can duplicate for hours and minutes as well but that is not the genius way of doing. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Below is the list of software as well as hardware I am using:-

-> Hardware Components :-

1. Arduino Nano
2. For now using only eight 8x8 Led Matrix Modules daisy chained(uses the MAX7219 chip).
3. A strong power supply for these hungry led(s) of 5 Volts and 10 Amps.
4. RTC DS1307.

-> Software Components :-

1. MD_Parola library by Marco_C.
2. This above code is a modified example named as push Wheel in the MD_MAX72xx library by Marco_C as well.
   Both of the libraries can be found easily here :-
   https://github.com/MajicDesigns
3. I am using the Standard RTC library found easily by the name RTClib.h in the arduino ide.

If any more information is required I am ready to provide. I Hope this is clear and any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: what animation are you taking about?  ... all I see is left scrolling text

Comment: @jsotola I don't know where the left scrolling text has come but the animation I am talking about is like that of a numerical counter it scrolls the existing digit upwards and scrolls a new digit from below. You can also click the first link I have provided and watch the photo or the video in that article.

Comment: @jsotola I see now, you saw the text at the very start of the video. That is not a issue for me, kind sir I request you to skip the video (The first one in the article under the title Story) to 1:02 seconds to see what animation I desire.

Comment: I looked at the second video at hackster.io again ... it is just a side scrolling YT subscriber counter ... no clock display ... the first image is not clickable for some reason

Comment: @jostula Well that was quite unfortunate. Check out this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mO98BBGWHkg
Please watch the left side of the display which is based on the code I have shared here :) I wanted to implement this scrolling up/down animation  to display time.

Comment: it makes more sense to add the link to the question,  instead of writing a comment ... comments are not for adding info to your post